# Почему документ не добавляется в MongoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

У меня есть поток, и на каждом чанке я добавляю новый документ в бд. В консоле пишется, что они добавляются, а на деле НЕТ.

```
 const User = require('../models/User');

  var fs = require('fs')
 , flow = require('xml-flow')
 , inFile = fs.createReadStream('./your-xml-file.xml')
 , xmlStream = flow(inFile)
 ;

 xmlStream.on('tag:person', function(person) {
     add(person.name)
 });



  const add = async function(name){
     await User.create({name: name})
  }
```

В базе создаётся только самый первый документ

Comment: простите, а какой участок кода отвечает за добавление?

Comment: @Дмытрык  await User.create({name: name})

Comment: @Дмытрык add(person.name)